# Linux kernel 3.3.4 Under Ubuntu 12.04

Tags: 12.04, kernel, updates

I just installed kernel 3.3.4 using the instructions from:

http://www.upubuntu.com/2012/05/how-to-install-linux-kernel-334-under.html

Anyway, now when I try to log into this version I just get a black screen that just hangs and nothing happens.

Does anyone have any ideas??

Thank you!

Comment: Please post this on the page where u got this idea and let him answer for it.You have to take extra care,when you do commands with sudo.It gives you the root power and if you have made any mistake,it is irrecoverable.

Comment: Did you try booting into one of the previous kernels? Hold left Shift at boot, a list of available kernels should pop up (this is the boot manager, Grub2). Select one of the previous kernels (I believe the default in 12.04 is 3.2.0), the system should boot normally. If it does, uninstall the 3.3.4 packages and run `sudo update-grub`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*Piskvor wrote:*

> Did you try booting into one of the previous kernels? Hold left Shift
>   at boot, a list of available kernels should pop up (this is the boot
>   manager, Grub2). Select one of the previous kernels (I believe the
>   default in 12.04 is 3.2.0), the system should boot normally. If it
>   does, uninstall the 3.3.4 packages and run `sudo update-grub`

I was able to go into previous version just fine. And now magically 'kernel 3.3.4' is working like a charm.

Comment: P.S. I cannot mark solved until tomorrow, or unless someone else makes a 'post' not a 'comment'.